# Display filenames with grep

Tags: grep, sort, cat, uniq

I'm looking for a way to display the filename when using this command:

```
cat *.tcp | grep "tcp" | grep "open" | sort | uniq
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`grep tcp *.tcp | grep open | sort -u`

Giving multiple filenames to `grep` will, by default, cause grep to prefix the matching output lines with the filename(s) they matched in. The only other change I made was to combine `sort | uniq` into `sort -u` (and to remove the quotes that are unnecessary here).

Comment: +1 although I think it has the potential for false matches if any of the *filenames* matches the pattern `open`: maybe that's not an issue in this particular application - otherwise perhaps consider replacing the second `grep` by an awk e.g. `awk -F: '$2 ~ /open/'`?

Comment: fair point on the filename possibly matching, although the OP's question implied that filenames would become part of the pipeline regardless. The awk statement you have now wouldn't quite work; it's only matching against field 2, and would miss matches in fields 3 & on.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep  -H 'tcp'
```

-H, --with-filename
Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is more than one file to search.

Comment: How would I incorporate this into my command and keep the formatting of the columns that my command gives me?